Different time expressions

When I had been  working  she visited me

As I have seen on this site my sentence is simply wrong and it's not idiomatic.

When I had been working for 2 hours she visited me

As I have seen on this site now my sentence is correct but it's true that it's not the most natural one
My question
My sentence without time was wrong when I added "for" is was okay. We have other time expressions like "Since the morning or all evening". Would they make my sentence correct or only "for" works?

When I had been working since the morning she visited me

When I had been working all evening she visited me



We normally spell out little numbers: "two".

No. "when I had been working since morning"  is a meaningless phrase, if it is meant to convey a particular time.  "when" there only makes sense when its meaning is "seeing as" or "considering".   "It was nearly midnight. An email from my boss arrived wanting to know when the report would be ready. I thought it was unfair of her, when I had been working since morning on this rush job and had been given no advance warning."

That is conditional when not temporal when.

You could say

Whenever I had been working since the morning, she visited me.

That is, on those occasions when I began work in the morning, at some time later that day, in the afternoon or evening, she would visit me. But that is not a specific time, just a viable range.
We know that it had to be afternoon or evening from "since the morning'.
That is once again conditional when, which presents a situation, not temporal when, that expresses a time.

let it be temporal. Why using "for +any time" is okay but other options provided such as "all morning" or maybe even without time express are incorrect?

@Marta  I am going to give you a bell.  Ring the bell when I have been working for five hours.   So far so good.  Now, ring the bell when I have been working since the morning.  Do you know when to ring the bell?

@marta  Here's another. I text you and say my ride never showed up at the train station, and I need a ride to the university since I have a lot of luggage.  You come to the train station.  I say to you "I have been waiting since the morning".   How long have I been waiting?

"When guests arrived I had been working" here we show that my working was ongoing before and maybe even at the same as guests arrived. Doesn't  it work the same if I put "when" before past perfect? "When I had been working the guests arrived"

@Marta Yes,ongoing up until the stated event (arrival of guests). The action occurred over a span of time. But the past perfect continuous does not express a point in time. This is gibberish:  "Please pick me up at the train station. My train arrives when you have been working."  Surely you understand the difference between a span of time and a point in time?

If I start work at noon, at 12:15 "I have been working for 15 minutes".  At 2PM, "I have been working for two hours".  at 5PM, "I have been working for five hours".  At 12:01PM, "I have been working for one minute".  The work is continuous.  From noon onward, up until the time of the utterance "I have been working", you were doing work. So you see, the "bare" perfect continuous ("I have been working" without "for n units of time") refers to a continuum.

Surely this is about common sense rather than the English language?
I had been working since the morning tells us when you started work; it says nothing about the length of time that had passed before her arrival. Isn't this the same in your language? You could say When she visited me at lunchtime I was tired because I had been working since early morning.
Similarly with your second example. 'All evening' until when?

How do you understand it with "for"?

Do you mean "when I had been working for two hours"? That's fine (assuming that a previous sentence has given an approximate time for starting work).

In my 2 sentence she arrived after two hours. Can't we say that in 4 she came after evening?

There is no exact moment when 'evening' becomes 'night' - for a particular individual, it's usually their bedtime - so when I had been working all evening doesn't specify at what time she visited.

so it possible grammatically but just doesn't make sense, right.? Only with for we say when excatly. What if I wrote "for hours"?

If we say that something happened after a period of ongoing activity, we have to state either when it happened or how long after the activity started, I repeat, isn't this the same in your language? For hours is no different grammatically from for two hours.

It is similar but with differences. What if I said "When I had been working all two hours"? Btw that's my last question. Thank you for help

You could say "When I had been working for all of two hours [something happened]". This implies that 2 hours is a long time.
